# Can I get a list of roads from Google Map Directions?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

When getting directions via the google maps javascript API v3, is it possible to get a list of all roads encountered on the journey?

The directions instructions obviously have the road names and these could be parsed/scraped out but I was wondering if there was a way of getting a definitive list.

Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even getting them from the directions response is not a 100% sure thing. Google does have some doozies for road names.

And no, afaik there is no way of just getting a list of road names without parsing the response.